# MYSQL_BIND solution needed for ? ? symbols

Tags: c++, mysql

I have question regarding to mysql database. when I'm trying to use following function MYSQL_BIND, the following error shows up

> MySQL query error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1

I have been looking on web and so far i haven't found a solution for my problem. I think i'm using wrong symbols in my query `query = "INSERT INTO users (num1, num2) values (?, ?)";`

Code is in c++

```
  MYSQL *conn;      // the connection
  MYSQL_RES *res;   // the results
  MYSQL_ROW row;    // the results row (line by line)
  MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
  MYSQL_BIND params[2];
  char *query;

  int var1 = 222;
  int var2 = 55;

  struct connection_details mysqlD;
  mysqlD.server = "localhost";  // where the mysql database is
  mysqlD.user = "root";     // the root user of mysql   
  mysqlD.password = "pass1"; // the password of the root user in mysql
  mysqlD.database = "db1";  // the databse to pick

  // connect to the mysql database
  conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

  memset(params, 0, sizeof(params));
  query = "INSERT INTO users (num1, num2) values (?, ?)";

 params[0].buffer = &var1;
 params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
 params[1].buffer = &var1;
 params[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;

  // assign the results return to the MYSQL_RES pointer
  //res = mysql_perform_query(conn, "show tables");


  mysql_perform_query(conn, query);
```

I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: but where do you bind the parameters to the query?

Comment: Have you checked the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-date-handling.html)?

Comment: _when I'm trying to use following function MYSQL_BIND, the following error shows up._ And where, exactly, did you try to use **function** `MYSQL_BIND`?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and listen to them.  `const char *query` is more appropriate here.